# Python / MySQL - Python INSERT INTO not inserting data

Tags: python, mysql

I'm testing a combination with Python and MySQL. For this example I want to insert data into a MySQL Database from my Python code. The problem I'm facing now is that there is no actual data inserted into the table when I run the SQL command via Python, but it works when I run it via the MySQL Command Line Client.

The DB name is `sha`.

The table was created as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sha_data (string varchar(255), sha256 char(64))
```

The Python code looks like this:

```py
import mysql.connector


def sql_run_command(sql, val):
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error on SQL command | {sql} | {e}')

    return result

# Database connect
db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="1234",
            database="sha"
        )

# Cursor creation
cursor = db.cursor()

# Command & variables
sql = "INSERT INTO sha_data (string, sha256) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("1", "6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b")
print(sql_run_command(sql, val))

# Connection close
db.close()
```

If I run this code the return is `[]`, and if I check it with `SELECT * FROM sha_data` there is no data.

I'm not quite sure where the problem is sitting. I would guess it's a simple syntax error.

Comment: You never `commit` your changes. Also You never run any `SELECT` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to commit your changes, add this line

> db.commit()

after executing the sql query, make sure to pass the db to the `sql_run_command` method, here's an example from the documentation
[Inserting Data Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)